# Symfony2. How to allow form to ignore extra fields?

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, cross-domain

I need to post some data to my Symfony form and I use `submit()` method for this.

But when request contains some extra data, I got error:

> "This form should not contain extra fields"

**Is it possible to let form miss the extra data using form configuration ?**

**Maybe another way for doing this exists?**

**Notice:** I need `submit()` method, not `handleRequest()` because I post my data through cross-domain ajax request, so form cannot be submitted this way. Reason: `isValid()` return `false`, because `isSubmitted()` return false.

**P.S.** Of course, I can create service that will be handle my request before passing it to the form, but maybe more elegant way exists.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Linked question doesn't take into account newer Symfony version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your Form Type:

```
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity',
            'translation_domain' => strtolower('entity_translation_domain'),
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        ));
    }
```

The `allow_extra_fields` will enable your form to receive the extra data

Comment: thanks for answer, it works! It seems, this option ignore extra data, so this is what I need.