# Extra field in form when changing HTTP method in Symfony / FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am building a REST API in Symfony using FOSRestBundle and I've stumbled upon a problem which seems to be trivial, but I can't find a nice solution.

I want to create a controller method to handle PATCH requests:

```
/**
 * @param Article $article
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @Patch("/articles/{slug}")
 * @ParamConverter("article", converter="doctrine.orm")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function patchAction(Article $article, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $entityManager->merge($article);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $view = $this->view($article)
            ->setTemplate('MyBundle::articleSubmit.html.twig')
            ->setTemplateVar('article')
        ;

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    $view = $this->view($form)
        ->setTemplate('MyBundle::articleForm.html.twig')
        ->setTemplateVar('form')
        ->setTemplateData(array('article' => $article))
    ;

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

I've configured form type like this, setting `method` option to `PATCH`:

```
namespace MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('content', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Article',
            'method' => 'PATCH',
        ));
    }
}
```

When I want to see this working, everything goes fine as long as I make a real `PATCH` request (for example using Open HttpRequester). But as most browsers support only GET and POST method, Symfony makes a trick adding `_method` parameter to regular `POST` request, and that's where my problem begins, because when testing this in browser I get the message:

> This form should not contain extra fields.

This is obviously because `ArticleType::getName()` returns empty string, but I would like my request parameters look more like `content=foo` than like `article[content]=foo`, as it's supposed in REST API. That's why I want this method to return blank value.

This works normally either when I change the action to `POST`, or when I set the form's name, or when I make a real `PATCH` request, but not when I'm sending a `POST` request with `_method` parameter.

I've managed to solve this problem creating a [body listener](http://symfony.com/doc/1.7/bundles/FOSRestBundle/body_listener.html) that removes fields having names prefixed by `_`, but that's more a dirty hack than a nice and clean solution.

I'm sure there must be some better workaround, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298641/symfony2-how-to-allow-form-to-ignore-extra-fields

Comment: Thank you @devilcius, adding `allow_extra_fields` option works fine. Just being curious: is there some other way if I would like to keep checking for extra fields with exception of parameters with special meaning in Symfony, like `_method` or `_token`?